# I have this format as object 2020-11-18 10:36:29.772234 +0000 UTC, want to convert to date time

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

`2020-11-20 23:07:59.381081 +0000 UTC`

I am reading a csv file with pandas and into a dataframe there is  a timestamp column that is object. I was not able to convert to datetime nor read the +0000 UTC into format

I tried the following:

```
datetimeObj = datetime.strptime('2020-11-21 22:16:25.389601 +0000 UTC', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')
```

but the %Z is giving me error.
Any advice for a beginner in the python & Pandas world
?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? It would also help if you could make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add also %z before %Z.

- %z refers to the offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM.
- %Z referts to Time zone name.

Try this:

```py
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2020-11-20 23:07:59.381081 +0000 UTC', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z %Z')
```

Comment: interestingly, the %Z actually doesn't do anything but ensure it's UTC or GMT. Other time zone abbreviations will raise an error. %z parses "+0000" to UTC, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64981768/10197418 In `pandas.to_datetime`, you can't use both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have datetime strings in that format in a pandas DataFrame, I'd suggest to remove the `+0000` since `pd.to_datetime` won't parse `+0000` and `UTC` *at the same time*.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':["2020-11-20 23:07:59.381081 +0000 UTC"]})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.replace(" +0000", "", regex=False))

# df['datetime']
# 0   2020-11-20 23:07:59.381081+00:00
# Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

Why not just strip the `UTC`? In contrast to a UTC offset of +0000, it's unambiguous. +0000 could also originate from a time zone that just happens to have UTC+0 at the time represented in the timestamp.