# Inconsistent datetime parse timezone in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

When I run the following in Python 3.X

```
import datetime

DATE_TS_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'

date_ts = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
date_ts = date_ts.strftime(DATE_TS_FORMAT)
print(date_ts)
date_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_ts, DATE_TS_FORMAT)
date_ts = date_ts.strftime(DATE_TS_FORMAT)
print(date_ts)
```

I get

```
2019-01-02 03:04:05.000000 UTC
2019-01-02 03:04:05.000000
```

Why did the timezone information disappear and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You don’t explain in your question if you did any research. Did you? The docs say for `strftime` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-strptime-behavior say “ %Z
In strftime(), %Z is replaced by an empty string if tzname() returns None; otherwise %Z is replaced by the returned value, which must be a string.” maybe this is what’s happening to you? What other research have you done?

Comment: [same problem, different story](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64975698/10197418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inconsistent indeed... The point is that `%Z` makes `strptime` *accept* certain strings (GMT, UTC and any value in time.tzname - [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail)), but doesn't actually make anything out of it. Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "2019-01-02 03:04:05.000000 UTC"
dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')

print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

The resulting datetime object is naive; no sign of UTC anymore.

To account for this behavior, you could post-process the datetime object, something like

```
if "UTC" in s: 
    dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

(which I think is a bit painful...) or replace "UTC" with something that `%z` parses to UTC<sup>1</sup>,

```
dt = datetime.strptime(s.replace("UTC", "+00:00"), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')

print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

(which I think is a bit ugly...) or use a suitable parser, e.g.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

dt = parse(s)

print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, tzinfo=tzutc())

print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'))
# 2019-01-02 03:04:05.000000 UTC
```

(which will be a bit slower if performance is an issue...).

---

<sup>1</sup> IMO, this is inconsistent as well; "+00:00" could also be the UTC offset of some time zone that happens to have a UTC offset of 0 hours at that time...